# TableView issue (weird Visualization)

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have a class (movieTable.m) with TableView populated with many cells.

As i Clicked one of them, the navigation controller brings in the other scene done in the StoryBoard.

When i get back, still with Navigation Controller, i find the TableView moved little bit down.
As I debugged the Hierarcy i found that UITableViewWrapperView is scrolled down from UITableView.

Edit: **The funny thing is: if i put a UiSegmentedControl in the UiView the issue disappears.**

Why this? i didn't tell the code to move it. Maybe I'm getting wrong with the timing?

so to making clear the ideas, there's two images:

[Hierarchy before/after changing the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsKjE.jpg)

The Code if you want to see it is in this following GitHub: [GitHub](https://github.com/sanxius/TabBarWithNav-Stack)

Thank you all for helping&hints.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

add

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

to your viewDidLoad of the moveiTable.m

Comment: no, it doesn't work for me, download the Project and try it yourself.